# Wallpaper bleeds through in Fullscreen mode

Tags: kubuntu, vlc, fullscreen, smplayer

Running Kubuntu 18.04. When I go to fullscreen mode in SMPlayer and VLC player (so not player specific), I see a vertical line about 1 pixel wide on the right side of the screen which of course is bothersome.

Wallpaper:
[image]

Right border showing wallpaper bleeding through in SMplayer video fullscreen mode:
[image]
(click to enlarge)

(source: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyGU7.jpg)

To confirm, I changed the wallpaper to all black and it's fine to watch but of course that's not an ideal solution.  The link above shows SMPlayer in fullscreen mode. Is there a setting or something I'm missing?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You attached a simple photo snap of a desktop

Comment: @JoKeR I think it's clear what OP meant from the screenshots: "*a vertical line about 1 pixel wide on the right side of the screen*" (second screenshot) even when VLC or SMPlayer is running full-screen.

Comment: What video card are you using? and video drivers? Did you install them manually?